# JSTL loop through Array to NOT display content

Tags: arrays, iteration, jstl, el

I'd like to use an "Array" in JSTL that looks like this

```
<c:set var="hideMe" value="${['A','B','C','D']}" scope="application" />
```

I also have a global VAR called `${checkPageName}` which has the name of the current page I am on in it, so I can check against it, as part of the logic (e.g. `<c:if test="${checkPageName != hideMe}"> ... </c:if>`)

The logic behind this is that if `A, B, C or D` exist then I will prevent a specific piece of information from being displayed to the user.

Does anyone know how I loop through a JSTL array?

The logic should then decide that if `A, B, C or D` DO NOT exist, then we display specific information to the user.

I have tried;

```
<c:forEach items="${hideMe}">
    <c:set var="hide" value="true" />
</c:forEach>

<c:if test="${hide != 'true'}">
    <div class="showMe">
        <h1>Hello Sweetie</h1>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: I have now fixed this myself using `<c:forTokens>`, see the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out in the end;

```
<c:set var="hideMe" value="false" />

<c:forTokens items="A,B,C,D" delims="," var="excludeDisplay">
    <c:if test="${checkPageName == excludeDisplay}">
        <c:set var="hideMe" value="true" />
    </c:if>
</c:forTokens>

<c:if test="${hideMe == 'false}">
    DO SOMETHING
</c:if>
```

checkPageName is a global variable I am checking against in my code to validate well, page names...

So I set a default VAR called hideMe with a value of false, I then use forTokens to create a VAR called excludeDisplay for values A, B, C or D.

I then check these values against my global variable and if they match overwrite the var hideMe with a value of true, this is then used to trigger the content I want to show. If the VAR is false show the content, if it is true, do nothing.

I hope this helps someone else, and I am happy to elaborate on some of the murkier points if anyone wants any more information...